# Perl Script to capture header in text and add to line

Tags: perl

I am trying to figure out how to rewrite my code to capture a header in my report.txt and add it to each line there after, once the header changes I want it to capture the new header and place it to each line there after. I have included a sample of what I am looking fore. I know my code is missing somethings to get my expected output which is why I am reaching out for help here. I am very new to perl so please any help or walk thru would be fantastic.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open (NEW, ">", "output.txt" ) or die "could not open:$!";

open (FILE, "<", "Report.txt") or die "could not open:$!";

    while (<FILE>) {
        print NEW if /^\h{3}\d/;
}
close (FILE);
close (NEW);
```

REPORT.TXT

```
DATE: 12/14/15
                          BAR.COMP1
    G2,,,,,,,USER LOGS
    DEVICE          EMULATOR   FROM-THRU    MINS  ROUTINE
    G1,,,,,,,USER LOGS
    COMPUTER04.1                 0726 0808    42    Process Account

              Account Name  Master Patient Number   Account Number
   0727       JOHN DOE      1234567899              1234567899   
   0730       JOHN DOE      1234567899              1234567897 
   0732       JOHN DOE      1234567899              1234567899   
   0742       JOHN DOE      1234567899              1234567893  
   0744       JOHN DOE      1234567899              1234567893

 DATE: 12/14/15
                          BAR.COMP2
     G2,,,,,,,USER LOGS
    DEVICE          EMULATOR   FROM-THRU    MINS  ROUTINE
    G1,,,,,,,USER LOGS
    COMPUTER04.1                 0726 0808    42    Process Account

               Account Name  Master Patient Number   Account Number
    0727       JOHN DOE      1234567899              1234567899   
    0730       JOHN DOE      1234567899              1234567897 
    0732       JOHN DOE      1234567899              1234567899   
    0742       JOHN DOE      1234567899              1234567893  
    0744       JOHN DOE      1234567899              1234567893
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT.TXT

```
BAR.COMP1   0727       JOHN DOE      1234567899         1234567899   
BAR.COMP1   0730       JOHN DOE      1234567899         1234567897 
BAR.COMP1   0732       JOHN DOE      1234567899         1234567899   
BAR.COMP1   0742       JOHN DOE      1234567899         1234567893  
BAR.COMP1   0744       JOHN DOE      1234567899         1234567893
BAR.COMP2   0727       JOHN DOE      1234567899         1234567899   
BAR.COMP2   0730       JOHN DOE      1234567899         1234567897 
BAR.COMP2   0732       JOHN DOE      1234567899         1234567899   
BAR.COMP2   0742       JOHN DOE      1234567899         1234567893  
BAR.COMP2   0744       JOHN DOE      1234567899         1234567893
```

Comment: Do your headers always start with `BAR`?

Comment: @sidyll Yes, the header always starts with BAR and contains the same amount of spaces.

Comment: Why does BAR.COMP2 have a space before `G2` compared to BAR.COMP1? And what have you tried?  This seems too simple without showing an attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. To capture  the header, first create a variable to
hold it:

```
my $header;
```

Now, inside your  loop, you need to  identify what is a  header line and
save it. Last change is to print  the header before the regular line, so
here is a refactored form of your code with these additions:

```
while (<FILE>) {
    if (/^\s*BAR/) {
        # Line is a header. Save it
        ($header) = /(BAR.\w+)/;
    } elsif (/^\h{3}\d/) {
        # Regular line. Print header and line
        print NEW $header, "\t", $_;
    }
}
```

This will go automatically. If the line  is a header it will save. If it
is a regular line it will print current header plus the line.

Comment: You said you were new to Perl, so let me know in case you didn't understand one of these lines used here :-)

Comment: You my friend are an absolute life saver! This is exactly what I was trying to do, but for the life of me could not figure out how to write the code. I was to embarrassed to post my attempts of my horrible Perl scripts which it why I posted the most basic one. hahaha... Thanks a million!

Comment: haha don't worry @PhoenixJay , no embarrassment with posting code in the future, we all learn if we make mistakes. Happy that it worked for you. Best wishes

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if you can help me with another code I have, one part copies the line just fine but the second part copies the line there after but bundles all the words together, for example   CLAIM FAILED - FILE NOTICE, export as "CLAIMFAILED-FILENOTICE"

Answer (score 0):

I've baked a lot of conjecture into this, as I don't know the specifics of your file...  for example, I see leading spaces that may just be the way you pasted the data.  Also, is that fixed width or tab-delimited?

Anyway, this is not at all elegant, but it may get you in the direction.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $NEW, ">", "c:/cdh/output.txt" or die "could not open:$!";
open my $FILE, "<", "c:/cdh/Report.txt" or die "could not open:$!";

my $file;
my $line_status = 0;

while (<$FILE>) {
  if (/^\s*DATE:/) {
    $line_status = 1;
    next;
  } elsif (/^\s+Account Name/) {
    $line_status = 2;
    next;
  }

  if ($line_status == 1) {
    chomp;
    tr/ //d;
    $file = $_;
    $line_status = 0;
    next;
  } elsif ($line_status == 2) {
    if (/\w/) {
      print $NEW "$file\t$_";
    } else {
      $line_status = 0;      
    }
  } 
}
close $FILE;
close $NEW;
```